# Android: save sound as ringtone and notification

Tags: android, audio, notifications, ringtone

I'm saving a sound from my app to be used as a ringtone or a notification sound. Here's part of my code, taken from [this](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-saving-a-sound-file-to-sd-from-resource-and-setting-as-ringtone/) page:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, soundName);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "artist");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

My understanding is that the sound will be saved as well as a ringtone, a notification sound and an alarm, as the flags are all set to "true". At least on the emulator this does work but on the actual device, the sound only shows up in the ringtone list, and I have no idea why.

EDIT: I've tried to investigate further: removing the line with "IS_RINGTONE" won't change anything (in case only one flag can be used at a time), the sound doesn't show up in the list with the notification-sounds.

Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards, Select0r

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible on FLASH CS5.5????
I have developed a soundboard on there that I really really need to get ringtones added to as a matter of urgency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played around with the path to get this solved and here's the solution I came up with so far:

On the emulator the path doesn't matter, the sound will appear in the ringtone as well as the notification-list.

On the phone, the sound will show up the the ringtone list if the file is saved to `/media/audio/ringtones` OR `/media/audio/` but NOT as a notification.
If I use the path `/media/audio/notifications` the sound finally appears in the notification-list (!) but NOT in the ringtones any more.

So it seems I have to save the sound *twice* to get it into both list? (But why does saving it once work on the emulator?)

If there's another way of getting sounds into both lists (or even three lists, there are alarm tones as well, I just didn't bother playing around with them) with only saving them once, please let me know. (Right now my workaround is a dialog to let the user choose whether to save the sound as a ringtone or a notification.)

Comment: I ran into this problem with my soundboard as well. As far as I can tell, you have to save it multiple times. I just used an AlertDialog that gave the option of where to save it which changed the path. But since you want to save it into both lists, I think you have to save it twice.

Comment: After the testing and researching, I believe that this is actually the way to go, thanks for confirming. I guess I'll stick with my workaround and ask the user where to save the file instead of just saving the sound twice (as you mentioned, too). Even though that was not my intention, I guess it's the better usability.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you try to change from MediaStore.Audio.Media to AudioColumns? Like this:

```
values.put(AudioColumns.ARTIST, "artist");
values.put(AudioColumns.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(AudioColumns.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
values.put(AudioColumns.IS_ALARM, true);
values.put(AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC, false);
```

The reference does not say MediaStore.Audio.Media is deprecated, but I do think AudioColumns is used now. I'm using it in my app and it seems to work.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I'll try that and get back to you if it works.

Comment: I tried to use AudioColumns but couldn't get it to work to save a ringtone or a notification sound on my device at all - so MediaStore.Audio.Media seems the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

You have to look into the media player API in Android 
i.e.android.media.MediaPlayer; 
android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener . Here it is: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary.... 
And that is how you play a sound on firing a click listener:

```
     private OnClickListener btnDontBeStupidListener = new 
OnClickListener() 
            { 
                public void onClick(View v) 
                { 
                  //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Don't Be Stupid audio file 
is being played", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                  final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(iMEvil.this, 
R.raw.stupid); 
                  //mp.start(); 
                  try { 
                          mp.start(); 
                          //mp.release(); 
                  }catch(NullPointerException e){ 
                        Log.v("MP error", e.toString()); 
                  } 
                  mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){ 
                      // @Override 
                      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) { 
                         mp.release(); 
                      } 
                 }); 
                } 
            };
```

Also, have you tried recording the sound while playing it? Try it and see if it works.

Comment: I *not* trying to play a sound and I'm *not* recording one. There's also *no* ClickListener involved. Did you even read the question?