# Saving File on Long Click

Tags: java, android

I have an app that plays mp3's. I want to make it so when you long click/press on the button it will save the mp3 file to there ringtones directory. Also want a toast notification if possible. Could someone shoot me into the right direction?

Thanks

EDIT:
This is what I have so far

```
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(AkaliMain.this, "Saved",5000);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toast.show();

                return false;

            }


        });
```

EDIT 2:
This is what I have now. Cant even get it to compile.

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EijmBrSL

Comment: Sorry for the delay, classes have started back so it has been crazy. What is the error on the compile? Also, how are your references to your mp3's stored? Path, uri in a sqlite db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google around some, there is TONS of information out there :). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417312/save-mp3-file-as-ringtone) question for saving mp3s as ringtones. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321332/detecting-which-selected-item-in-a-listview-spawned-the-contextmenu-android) question for a good example of an onItemLongClickListener (using a listview). 
And this is how to make a toast message:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Hello from Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

So your onItemLongClickListener would look something like this:

```
myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
  @Override public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
   //... code to save mp3 file...
   Toast.makeText(context, "File saved as ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   return false;
  }
```

});

While I could just give you teh complete codez, you wouldn't learn anything in the process :)

EDIT: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534745/save-as-ringtone-from-contextmenu) question for more help on saving your mp3 to the ringtones directory. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918325/android-save-sound-as-ringtone-and-notification) is another good one, which links to [this](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-saving-a-sound-file-to-sd-from-resource-and-setting-as-ringtone/) great post.

Comment: I just added what I just put in. Im trying to find out how to actually save the file now.

Comment: @Jack

Ive look at both links to try and save the files and couldnt figure it out. Any help?

Comment: @jack

So for being such a noob, not a java pro yet :P
ive basically copied all the codes on all the links you sent me and I cant seem to get it to even run.

Comment: @jack

Im not getting any errors I cant even run it on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at FileOutputStream and File classes